# Fourier transform and rotations in 3d

Tags: lie-groups, operator-theory, fourier-transform

Let $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ be a Schwartz function invariant under rotations in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $\hat f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ be its Fourier transform, i.e. $\hat f(p)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f(x) \exp(-i p\cdot x) d x$. The fourier transform $\hat f$ is rotationally invariant. Hence, $\hat f(p)=F(|p|^2)$ for some $F\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$.

Is it true that for $g\in L^2(\mathbb{S}^2)$ it holds $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f(x) g(R_x y)dx = (F(\Delta) g)(y)$, where $R_x y$ is the rotation of the vector $y$ around the vector $x$ by an angle $|x|$ and $\Delta$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$.

The above formula follows formally from the representation $R_x = \exp(-i L\cdot x)$ and $\Delta=L^2=L_1^2+L_2^2+L_3^2$, where $L=(L_1,L_2,L_3)$ are the generators of rotations (the problem is the non-commutativity of the operators $L_j$; however, this should not be an issue for $f$ rotationally invariant).

Comment: What do you mean by angle $\lvert x\rvert$ when one deal with vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$? Also that would mean that the integral dx should be simplified by polar coordinates to an explicit form (note that FT of spherical functions is spherical, hence $f$ is spherical itself).

Comment: $|x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^3}$ is the usual norm of the vector $x$ and by assumption $f(x)$ is a function of $|x|$.

Comment: You have not addressed @Asaf's question - you have written "around the vector $x$ by an angle $|x|$" but this makes no sense.

Comment: The rotation of the vector $y$ around the vector $x$ by an angle $|x|$ means the rotation in the plane perpendicular to $x$ by an angle $|x|$.

Comment: I just saw your reply. This usage of $|x|$ is inconsistent with the (standard) use of the symbol that is in your second comment.